# wp_session variables being overwritten by $_POST

Tags: php, wordpress, post, session-variables

I am trying to post a form to $wp_session which is working fine - however when I perform it again it overwrites the array that I have put there in the first place, I need the arrays to carry on building up like a collection / shopping basket.

My form:

```
<form class="form1" method="post" action="" id="form1">
<fieldset>
<ul>
        <label for="name">Exercise ID</label><span>
        <input type="text" name="ExerciseID" placeholder="Exercise ID" class="required" role="input" aria-required="true"/></span>

        <label for="name">Exercise Reps</label><span>
        <input type="text" name="Sets" placeholder="Sets" class="required" role="input" aria-required="true"/></span>

        <label for="name">Exercise Reps</label><span>
        <input type="text" name="Reps" placeholder="Sets" class="required" role="input" aria-required="true"/></span>

        <input  class="submit .transparentButton" value="Next" type="submit" name="Submit"/> 

</ul>
<br/>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

And the php:

```
<?php

global $wp_session;

if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
 $wp_session['collection'] = array($POST['ExerciseID'],$_POST['Sets'],$POST['Reps']);

}

print_r($wp_session);

?>
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: For one thing, a few underscores missing in `array($POST['ExerciseID'],$_POST['Sets'],$POST['Reps'])` try `array($_POST['ExerciseID'],$_POST['Sets'],$_POST['Reps'])` those are superglobals and 99% of them need to be `$_XXX`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have a basket, you have to add the products to an array:

```
<?php

global $wp_session;

if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
 $wp_session['collection'][] = array($_POST['ExerciseID'],$_POST['Sets'],$_POST['Reps']);

}

print_r($wp_session);

?>
```

You may want to organize the array by ExerciseID, so you can add to the quantity. I would advice you to create some objects, as they will be more flexible than arrays

Comment: You left out the part where OP missed two underscores. As per [`my comment`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22895443/wp-session-variables-being-overwritten-by-post#comment34939699_22895443) ;-)

Comment: The OP problem is that the variable is overwritten and the question is how to add it as a shopping basked, not that the data is incorrect (as the wrong values will come as nulls)

Comment: I know that, I was just stating that "one" of the problems is the two missing underscores. Usually, we point out those mistakes.

Comment: This is still not working for me - it keeps overwriting the original array thats created giving me
    `array(3) {
  ["ExerciseID"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "ID"
  }
  ["Sets"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  ["Reps"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
}`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for this: instead of overwriting you append a new entry to your "session variable" at each run:

```
<?php

global $wp_session;

if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
 $wp_session[]['collection'] = array($_POST['ExerciseID'],$_POST['Sets'],$_POST['Reps']);
}

print_r($wp_session);
?>
```

Note the additional `[]` in the left hand side of the assignment.

Comment: As per [`Read this`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22895443/wp-session-variables-being-overwritten-by-post#comment34939699_22895443) you're doing the same mistake.

Comment: True, thanks for mentioning. Fixed that. Though actually that was not the OPs question.

Comment: You're welcome. You may want to add that in your answer, stating the two missing underscores. I do know that, but it's good to point out errors made.

Comment: @Fred-ii- The OP claims his code works in that aspect. So I assume that either was a typo by himself (so not a real issue), or he indeed has a `$POST` variable.

Comment: That is **impossible**. Using `$POST` will never ever ever work. It's a [**superglobal**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php). Probably why only one result gets through. Either the OP is lying, or made a typo, but I find that rather hard to believe since there are two missing underscores; or did a lazy copy/paste.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Hey hey, calm down. Don't claim anyone is "lying" or something is "impossible" just because things don't apply to your personal view. `$POST` certainly is _not_ a superglobal. Actually you state that yourself! As I wrote: maybe that variable exists, that does not mean it has to be a superglobal. You simply can create such a variable. Who are you to tell what is impossible or if someone else is lying?

Comment: *"$POST certainly is not a superglobal."* --- Oh that's right [**What was I thinking?**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) <= that's a link by the way.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Maybe you should start to read the actual comments instead of replying to what you _think_ someone writes.

Comment: Soooo... That does not work - still only creates one array not adding a new one each time the form is submitted? Thanks again.

Comment: Actually I have and you're the one who's misinformed. So, don't go telling me or passing information around that `$_POST` isn't a superglobal. @arkascha I said `$_POST` and not `$POST` I think we got a communication breakdown here. As per my [`original comment`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22895443/wp-session-variables-being-overwritten-by-post/22895516?noredirect=1#comment34939699_22895443)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Sorry, could we please end this is chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50456/fred