# Pass form Variables to $_SESSION by AJAX in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have several forms on my site that manipulate the data that is held in $_SESSION. I am looking to AJAXify all of these. The main example is below.

FORM:

```
<form class="form-inline" id="addExerciseForm" role="form" method="post" action=" ">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="hidden" name="ExerciseID" type="text" class="form-control" value="29">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group lightboxFormText">
            <label class="lightboxFromElementLabels" for="exerciseDescription">Description</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" name="Description" rows="3"><?php echo the_content(); ?></textarea>
        </div>
        <br />
        <br />
        <div class="form-group lightboxFormElements">
            <label class="lightboxFromElementLabels" for="exerciseSets">Sets</label>
            <input type="text" name="Sets" class="form-control" placeholder="Sets">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group lightboxFormElements">
            <label class="lightboxFromElementLabels" for="exerciseReps">Reps</label>
            <input type="text" name="Reps" class="form-control" placeholder="Reps">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group lightboxFormElements">
            <label class="lightboxFromElementLabels" for="exerciseReps">Load</label>
            <input type="text" name="Load" class="form-control" placeholder="Load">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group lightboxFormElements">
            <label class="lightboxFromElementLabels" for="exerciseReps">Rest</label>
            <input type="text" name="Rest" class="form-control" placeholder="Rest">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group lightboxFormElements">
            <label class="lightboxFromElementLabels" for="exerciseReps">Tempo</label>
            <input type="text" name="Tempo" class="form-control" placeholder="Tempo">
        </div>
        <br />
        <br />
        <div class="modal-footer">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="addExercise">
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Add to Collection</input>
        </div>
    </div>
        </form>
```

Javascript:

```
 jQuery('#addExerciseForm').submit(addExercise);

function addExercise(){

var newExercise = jQuery(this).serialize();

jQuery.ajax({
type:"POST",
url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
data: addExerciseForm,
success:function(data){
jQuery("#feedback").html(data);
}
});

return false;
}
```

Function: 
function addExercise(){
  global $post;

echo $description;

```
$_SESSION['collection'][$_POST['ExerciseID']] = array(
$description => $_POST['Description'],
$sets => $_POST['Sets'],
$reps => $_POST['Reps'],
$load => $_POST['Load'],
$rest => $_POST['Rest'],
$tempo => $_POST['Tempo']);

$description = $_SESSION['collection'][$exid]['Description']; 
$sets = $_SESSION['collection'][$exid]['Sets'];
$reps = $_SESSION['collection'][$exid]['Reps'];
$rest = $_SESSION['collection'][$exid]['Rest'];
$load = $_SESSION['collection'][$exid]['Load'];
$tempo = $_SESSION['collection'][$exid]['Tempo'];

die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_addExercise', 'addExercise');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_addExercise', 'addExercise');
```

I understand that I can go straight from jQuery VAR -> session Var however this code is cobbled together from my original $_POST Submit button. The AJAX side of things has got me confused, and throwing in the mix the different way that Wordpress handles things, any assistance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Using $_SESSION in WordPress isn't the same as a standard php script approach. You have to do things like factoring in when in the sequence of WordPress loading, does the session get set, created, etc.

Have you seen the WP Session Manager? It makes working with sessions in WordPress much more pain-free. Check out https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-session-manager/

Comment: I tried using WP_Session however I found it wasn't working, even with an extensive question on this forum I could not get it to create my array and correctly populate it on $_POST.

Comment: I have re implemented wp_session and am getting the same issue that I had [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22895443/wp-session-variables-being-overwritten-by-post#comment34939699_22895443) everytime I run $_POST it overwrites the items in the array.

Comment: I wonder if the session ID is different on the $_POST because it's not actually your own session? IE, it's one the server is making.. Sorry I can't help!